# Oracle query optimization on matching/searching for first match on ID with multiple tables

Tags: oracle, query-optimization

This a dummy query that illustrates what I am trying to do. In essence I have one main table with ID's and then two sub-tables. What I am trying to optimize is when it finds a match in the first sub-table (in this case TableA) -take a specific value and then move to next ID.
In the real query, both sub-tables are created fairly quickly-just when I am trying to link them all with the left joins is killing the query though.

I also need to include ID1 even if no value in Tables A/B
Any thoughts?

TIA
Lawrence

```
with main_t as (select 1 as ID from dual union all
                select 2 as ID from dual union all
                select 3 as ID from dual),
    TABLEA as (select 2 as ID, 'ABC' as Var1 from dual union all
               select 3 as ID, 'DEF' as Var1 from dual),
    TABLEB as (select 3 as ID, 'ABC' as Var1 from dual)
    
     select main_t.ID,coalesce(TABLEA.var1,tableb.VAR1) from main_t
          left join TABLEA on main_t.ID=TABLEA.ID
          left join TABLEB on main_t.ID=TABLEB.ID
        order by main_t.ID;
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the requirements. When you say TableA and TableB being "created", do you mean they are being populated in some procedure you are calling? Does the main table contain all of the information you are trying to output and TableA and TableB are just helper tables?

Comment: Main Table has just the ID, TAbleA and TableB are CTE tables (temp) for the query

Comment: There is no enough information for good analysis. We need: tables statistics, indexes and real execution plan with execution statistics